# Doxygen document method taking in-line block

Tags: objective-c, c, doxygen

In [this file](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/interface_typhoon_patcher.html), the method parameters containing inline blocks don't show up correctly. Is there a way to fix this?

Do typedef'd blocks work?

[Here's](https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon/blob/master/Source/Test/TyphoonTestUtils.h) is the source for the file being documented.

Comment: Looks like a bug in doxygen's parser. Can you file a bug report for it here? https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen

Comment: Sure will do! I figured it might be a bug, but couldn't find the issue tracker. I was looking on the GitHub page, but of course that's only a mirror. Perhaps you could include a link in the README?

Comment: Well it is there already: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen#issues-bugs-requests-ideas

Comment: heh- it is too. somehow I missed it. . I won't ask you to make it flash in hot-pink ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, and has now been enrolled in the Doxygen backlog.

In the meantime, extracting a typedef for the anonymous block parameter will workaround the problem.